# How to add onTouchListener and more bottom containers for drag and drop app

Tags: android, android-studio, drag-and-drop

I followed this tutorial to make an drag and drop app: http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/download/4-tutorials/38-drag-and-drop-tutorial.html

I want help with this:

1. How to change draglistener so it listens to which image is placed in the different containers and accept/reject the right/wrong image? Do I have to create one listener for each container?
2. How to implement onTouchListener instead of longClick to this code?

Here is an image of what I want to do:

[This is how I want the drag and drop to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmggW.png)

Here is the code:

```
public class DragActivity extends Activity implements OnDragListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

private static final String TAG = "status";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag);

    // listeners for images
    findViewById(R.id.image1).setOnLongClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.image2).setOnLongClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.image3).setOnLongClickListener(this);

    // drag event listeners for the target layout containers
    findViewById(R.id.top_container).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.bottom_container).setOnDragListener(this);

    // containers that I want to add instead of bottom_container
    findViewById(R.id.left_container).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.center_container).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.right_container).setOnDragListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View imageView) {
    ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
    View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(imageView);
    imageView.startDrag(clipData, shadowBuilder, imageView, 0);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View receivingLayoutView, DragEvent dragEvent) {
    View draggedImageView = (View) dragEvent.getLocalState();

    switch (dragEvent.getAction()) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            Log.i(TAG, "drag action started");

            if (dragEvent.getClipDescription()
                    .hasMimeType(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Can accept this data");

                return true;

            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Can not accept this data");

            }

            return false;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.i(TAG, "drag action entered");
            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            Log.i(TAG, "drag action location");
            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.i(TAG, "drag action exited");
            return true;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            switch (draggedImageView.getId()) {
                case R.id.image1:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image 1");
                    return false;
                case R.id.image2:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image 2");
                    ViewGroup draggedImageViewParentLayout
                            = (ViewGroup) draggedImageView.getParent();
                    draggedImageViewParentLayout.removeView(draggedImageView);
                    LinearLayout bottomLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) receivingLayoutView;
                    bottomLinearLayout.addView(draggedImageView);
                    draggedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    return true;
                case R.id.image3:
                    Log.i(TAG, "Image 3");
                    return false;
                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, "in default");
                    return false;
            }

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

            Log.i(TAG, "drag action ended");
            Log.i(TAG, "getResult: " + dragEvent.getResult());
            if (!dragEvent.getResult()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "setting visible");
                draggedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            return true;

        default:
            Log.i(TAG, "Unknown action type received by OnDragListener.");
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and what the error is?

Comment: Wondering? Did you tried googling anything? If yes, what have you tried so far.? update the question with the same.

Comment: I change my question!